# How do I re-apply for a job after updating my resume?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

I applied for a job few months ago but now my resume is much improved with new skills and certifications. Job is still listed on Stack Overflow but when I go to apply that, it says you have already applied for this job. How can I reapply for same job again?